# Axios request always sends back 200

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm making a very simple PUT request (see below.) For some reason no matter what response code I send back from my express server axios sees 200. In my express logs, it shows the correct response:

```
PUT /v1/org/password/reset 404 339.841 ms - 71
```

This is the line of code sending the response server side:

```
res.json({ message: 'Could not find user with that token or the token expired.' }).status(404);
```

I know this line is being triggered because the body logged to the browser console shows that same message. See screenshot.[image]

The only thing I can think of is the browser is caching the response?

```
    axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/v1/org/password/reset`, {
     password: "example",
     token: "19u8e8j2039d3d32blahblah"
   })
 .then(function (response) {
   if(response.status == 200){
       console.log("success",response)
     //handle success here
   }
 })
 .catch(function (error) {
   console.log("error", error);
   //handle error here
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting the status first like so

```
res.status(404).json({ message: 'Could not find user with that token or the token expired.' });
```

Comment: That fixed it! Any idea why the order matters there?

Comment: some functions are chainable, some are not.  .json() actually fires off the response.  .status() is chainable.  Thus invoking .json() first does NOT return a chainable method, and instead defaults to status code of 200.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the backend side. Try to return response this way:

```
res.status(404).json({ message: 'Could not find user with that token or the token expired.' });
```

According to Express 4 documentation - https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html

> Middleware functions are executed sequentially, therefore the order of
>   middleware inclusion is important.

So when you invoke "send" method Express writes out the http body content to the response, that's why first you need to fill headers.